# Задать дефолтное значение для Singleton

Tags: c++, static, singleton, gmock

Имеется **класс-синглтон** для покрытия тестами используя **gmock framework**. Некоторые методы (как например *method1()* в примере) изменяют значения полей класса во время вызова. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ задавать дефолтные значения полям класса без изменения структуры класса?

Пример:

```
class TestingClass
{

private:

TestingClass(): _field1(0)
              , _field2(0)
{

}
TestingClass(const TestingClass&){}
TestingClass & operator=(const TestingClass &){}

public:

static TestingClass Instance()
{
    static TestingClass instance;
    return instance;
}

void method1()
{
    _field1 = 777;
}
void method2()
{
    _field1 = 888;
}
void Show()
{
    std::cout << "\nField1 - " << _field1
              << "\nField2 - " << _field2
              << "\n";
}

//other methods...


private:

int _field1;
int _field2;

};
```

Comment: разве в конструкторе _field1(0), вы не задаёте дефолтные значения?

Comment: может проблема в том, что в Instance() надо возвращать ссылку? `static TestingClass& Instance()`

Answer (score 0):

Для гарантированной инициализации используете синглтон Майерса:

```
Foo& fooInstance(){
   static Foo value (init_value);
   return value;
}
```

Или так:

```
Foo& fooInstance(){
   static Foo value = []{
      Foo initValue;
      initValue.setValue(42);
      return initValue;
   }();
   return value;
}
```

В любом месте вызова этой функции будет возвращена корректная ссылка. В случае возможного многопоточного обращения сам класс Foo должен быть потокобезопасным, тогда и синглтон будет потокобезопасным (начиная с C++11).

P.S. В вашем коде достаточно инициализировать поля класса в конструкторе и возвращать в `instаnce` ссылку, а не копировать объект.